# SSIS derived column error (cast type)

Tags: ssis, casting, derived-column

I am trying to sum 2 columns (adjustment due day and expiration day):

```
DATEADD("dd",(DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode,ExpirationDate)
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast
SSIS Error Code `DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR*`
```

I thought it could be because of nulls so wrote the following:

```
(DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode > 0 ? (DATEADD("dd",

(DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode,ExpirationDate) : "null"
```

But still getting the same error, any recommendations?

Comment: Hi Rachel, May I have a couple of examples of rows of your data to view what your data looks like in the table, please?

Comment: @Ryan  sure,  ExpirationDate : 1999-11-15  (date)        AdjustmentDueDaycode : 90  (varchar(3))

Comment: Does DateAdd("dd", 90, ExpirationDate) work?  How about (DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode?  Finally, does DATEADD("dd",((DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode),ExpirationDate) work?

Comment: (DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDayCode  Doesn't work and DateAdd("dd", 90, ExpirationDate)  does work, so I guess the issue is casting Adjust.duedate

Answer (score 0):

AdjustmentDueDaycode needs to become type `BIGINT`.

IE)
`DATEADD("dd", CONVERT(BIGINT, (DT_I4)AdjustmentDueDaycode),ExpirationDate)`

Comment: It won't let me change the data type of that column, gives me error :  The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

Comment: I changed the example to use BIGINT instead of INT in the conversion due to the DT_I4 data type.  I hope it works for you!